# Check if the current time has just passed 12 o'clock in BACKGROUND

Tags: ios, swift, date

I want to check if the current time (24 hours or 12 hours am/pm) has just passed 12 o'clock.
I did something like that in a view, but in this case I checked if it was not yet 12 in the morning:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hora = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutos = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
if hora < 12 && minutos <= 59 { ... }
```

I don't know if I explained it well... I was wondering if I can check if the time has passed in AppDelegate, always in background, and execute a function when 12 am has passed. It is possible?

Comment: No, there is no way to execute code in the background at a specific time on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 oh, it is a pity ): well, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will achieve at least in iOS framework.

Apple won't allow you to execute code at a certain time interval in background. Because it's almost similar what some malwares do.

**Additional:** But if you don't want to execute code in background rather when in your app's foreground then it's possible using **timer**.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, Local Notifications might be of use to you:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1

You can schedule them and they will be delivered to the user even when your app is in the background or not running. The user may then launch your app with a particular action on the notification.